# counting user input numbers from range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

So my problem is that this program should take inputted numbers (e.g `5`) would be `0+1+2+3+4` and the sum would be `10`. I have gotten it to list these numbers but how do I make this code to count them?

```
num1 = int(input("How many laps?: "))
num2 = int(0)

for lap in range (num1):
   num2 = lap
   print("Sum is:" , (num2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple solution is as follows

```
num1 = int(input("How many laps?: "))
print(sum(range(num1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing it with a loop like you were trying

```
num1 = int(input("How many laps?: "))

list = []

for lap in range (num1):
   list.append(lap)

listSum = sum(list)

print(listSum)
```